# Removing multiple newline characters from git history

Tags: regex, git, bfg-repo-cleaner

I was trying to clean my repo from multiple empty lines in code (more than 4) with bfg repo cleaner. I tried various regular expressions, but didn't come up with a solution. The closest result I achieved was simply removing all new lines from a file.

Any ideas how I can do this with bfg or any other tool?

Comment: Can you paste you actual command that you used with bfg ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

```
(\r?\n){4,}
```

And replace it with this

```
\n
```

- It will accept the UNIX and the Windows linebreak (`\r?\n`).
- It matches if at least 4 line endings are consecutive (without spaces on each of the lines)
- All the consecutive linebreak characters are replaced by a single UNIX linebreak (`\n`)

---

**Here is an executable example:**

```js
var text = document.getElementById("main").innerHTML; // read HTML because it is easier to write linebreaks in HTML
var regex = /(\r?\n){4,}/g;
var replacement = "\n";

var result = text.replace(regex, replacement);
console.log(text);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="main">








line1




line2


line3





</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
In bfg replacements.txt file it would look like:

regex:(\r?\n){4,}==>\n

in case someone wondered.